# How to create view/renderer for the polymorphic model

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I need to render polymorphic models in different situations.

Model's base class:

```
abstract class BaseDiscount {
  abstract public function createRenderer(IDiscountRendererFactory $factory);
}
```

IDiscountRendererFactory:

```
interface IDiscountRendererFactory {

  /**
   * @return IDiscountRenderer
   */
  public function createDiscountRenderer(Discount $model);

  /**
   * @return IDiscountRenderer
   */
  public function createActionRenderer(Action $model);
}
```

Discount model class:

```
class Discount extends BaseDiscount {
  public function createRenderer(IDiscountRendererFactory $factory) {
    return $factory->createDiscountRenderer($this);
  }
}
```

Action model class:

```
class Action extends BaseDiscount {
  public function createRenderer(IDiscountRendererFactory $factory) {
    return $factory->createActionRenderer($this);
  }
}
```

IDiscountRenderer:

```
interface IDiscountRenderer {
  public function render();
}
```

---

In the client module I have:

```
class ConcreteDiscountRenderer implements IDiscountRenderer {
  public function __construct(Discount $model) {
    //do something
  }

  public function render() {
    //do something
  }
}

class ConcreteActionRenderer implements IDiscountRenderer {
  public function __construct(Action $model) {
    //do something
  }

  public function render() {
    //do something
  }
}

class ConcreateDiscountRendererFactory implements IDiscountRendererFactory {
  public function createDiscountRenderer(Discount $model) {
    return new ConcreteDiscountRenderer($model);
  }
  public function createActionRenderer(Action $model) {
    return new ConcreteActionRenderer($model);
  }
}

$repository = new DiscountRepository();

/** @var BaseDiscount[] $discounts */
$discounts = $repository->findAll();
$factory = new ConcreateDiscountRendererFactory();

foreach ($discounts as $discount) {
  $discount->createRenderer();
  $renderer = $discount->createRenderer($factory);
  $renderer->render();
}
```

In other application parts may be other implementatations.

I think I got some combination of Visitor and AbstractFactory patterns.
Is it a right approach or is there a better solution?

**UPD**

If I add new model class, like DiscountProgramm extends BaseDiscout, I have to refactor IDiscountFactoryInterface and all it's realizations. Is there an approach which allows to avoid that?

Comment: If your code works, you should ask your question in [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Phaberest is right, but I wonder if there's another way around this. @AnthonyZh, are there any thing the code doesn't do which you want it to? If you could rephrase your question to include those, perhaps? That is: *how would you like the solution you have to improve; what's bad about it?*.

Comment: If I add new model class, like DiscountProgramm extends BaseDiscout, i have to refactor IDiscountFactoryInterface and all it's realizations. Is there an approach which allows to avoid it?

Comment: I believe too it's a proper question for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I have this [one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129147/php-get-a-view-object-for-a-polymorphic-model) there, but some guy there told me that it is not a code review question